# Google Analytics: Session-scope custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

What happens when you set a session-scope custom dimension more than once in the same session?

Simple question for ya.

EDIT: In case it wasn't clear... suppose you have a session-scope custom dimension, defined by:

```
name: my_custom_dimension
index: 1
scope: Session
```

and then do

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'LOL');
```

and then in the same session do

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'LMAO');
```

what will the reports show is the value of dimension1 for that session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Only the last value is applied to all the hits in the session](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#processing):

[image]

Comment: I am understanding the use of user and session scope custom dimension. But still not getting the main difference between them.
Both are maintaining the values of dimensions in their sessions.Then what's the major difference between them. Any clear example for this?

Comment: The user scoped dimensions maintains a value over multiple sessions. The difference is in the reporting. If you have a custom dimension e.g. for login status then a segment with that dimension in session scope will segment for all users that had logged-in session in the selected timeframe. The same dimension is user scope will segment for users with sessions in the selected timeframe who have been logged it in some session, even if that session was outside the selected timeframe. Most of the time the values are close, but they don't have to be.